# Remove the dot from the figure caption and in the text

Tags: floats, formatting, captions

For Figures, I'm getting the following for the caption:

Figure 1.: Caption

In the text, I get the following:

See Figure 1. for blah blah blah

I'm fine with the colon in the caption, but I want to remove the trailing dot in both the caption and when it's referenced in the text. Here's a minimum working example:

```
\documentclass[12pt, floatsintext]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{trace}
\usepackage{caption}
%\DeclareCaptionLabelSeparator{none}{ }
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{images/}}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{tocloft}%

% set page numbers just after chapter titles
\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{}
\renewcommand{\cftchapafterpnum}{\cftparfillskip}

% set page numbers just after section titles
\renewcommand{\cftsecleader}{}
\renewcommand{\cftsecafterpnum}{\cftparfillskip}

\renewcommand{\cftsubsecleader}{}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsecafterpnum}{\cftparfillskip}

\renewcommand{\cftfigleader}{}
\renewcommand{\cftfigafterpnum}{\cftparfillskip}
\renewcommand{\cfttableader}{}
\renewcommand{\cfttabafterpnum}{\cftparfillskip}
\renewcommand{\cftequleader}{}
\renewcommand{\cftequafterpnum}{\cftparfillskip}


\newcommand{\atoc}[1]{\addtocontents{toc}{\bigskip #1\par}}

\setmainfont{Times New Roman}  

\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\large\bfseries\filcenter}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{20pt}{\large}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}
  {0pt}{30pt}{20pt}
\counterwithout{figure}{chapter}\counterwithout{table}{chapter}

\begin{document}

\newgeometry{left=4.0cm, right=2.54cm, top=2.54cm, bottom=2.54cm}

\setcounter{page}{1}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\pagestyle{plain}


%=======================================================
% ============== TOC AND LISTS ===========
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{\hfill\bfseries\large Table of Contents\hfill}   
\renewcommand{\cftaftertoctitle}{\hfill}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@dotsep}{10000}
\makeatother
\renewcommand{\cftchapaftersnum}{.}%
\tableofcontents
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\newpage




\renewcommand{\cftloftitlefont}{\hspace*{\fill}\large\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cftafterloftitle}{\hspace*{\fill}}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\textbf{List of Figures}}
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\arabic{figure}.}
{\renewcommand{\addvspace}[1]{} \listoffigures}
\newpage



%=======================================================
% ============== CHAPTERS ===========
\newgeometry{left=4.0cm, right=2.54cm, top=2.54cm, bottom=2.54cm}
\setlength{\parindent}{36pt}
\doublespacing
\setcounter{page}{1}
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyheadoffset{0cm}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} 
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyhead[R]{\thepage}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \fancyhf{}%
  \fancyhead[R]{\thepage}%
}

\atoc{\textbf{Chapters}}
\chapter{Introduction}

See Figure~\ref{fig:puppies} for cute puppies. 

\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.1]{cute_puppies.jpeg}
    \caption[Cute Puppies]{Cute Puppies}
    \label{fig:puppies}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Here's what I'm seeing ...

[image]

Edit: A commenter pointed out the following line:

```
\renewcommand{thefigure}{\arabic{figure}.}
```

This was added to get the period in the List of Figures. If I remove that line, then it solves my problem, but then I lose the period in the list.

How can I accomplish both? Have the period in my List of Figures, but not in the caption and the text?

Comment: Why `\renewcommand{thefigure}{\arabic{figure}.}` if you don't want the period?

Comment: I didn't realize that was affecting it. I'm still learning LaTeX. However, when I remove the period, it also removes it in the List of Figures. There I do want a period. Is there another way to get the period in the List of Figures. For example: 1. Cute Puppies 1

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution. To keep the period in the List of Figures,
I added the following line:

```
\renewcommand\cftfigaftersnum{.} % affix "." after figure number
```

I then removed this line:

```
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\arabic{figure}.}
```